# Python while loop ask more than once for input

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I've been trying to solve the issue with guessing the number program,
The first number the program has to print Ans which is (Startlow + Starthigh)/2 and then Ans gets updated depends on the input

I can't figure out why my while loop keeps waiting for the input for at least 2 times until it prints the results even if I press l or h (unless I press c) which breaks the loop

```
Startlow = 0
Starthigh = 100
Ans = (Startlow + Starthigh)/2
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")

while True:
    print("Is your secret number " + str(int(Ans)))
    if input() == "c":
        print("Game over,Your secret number was: "+str(int(Ans)))
        break
    elif input() == "l":
        Startlow = Ans
        Ans = (Startlow + Starthigh)/2
    elif input() == "h":
        Starthigh = Ans
        Ans = (Startlow + Starthigh)/2
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
```

any help appreciated :)

Comment: Every time you call `input()`, Python waits for input. Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 2):

You should be asking for input once in the loop, and then comparing that answer to the items you want.

You are instead requesting a (potentially different) answer at each of your conditionals.

The number of questions asked depends on how many conditionals you fall through.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
x = input()
if x == "c":
  #And so on...
```